# How do you use InTune device configuration policy to govern password complexity of AzureAD domain users

Tags: azure-active-directory, intune

I am using AzureAD and Intune, I have joined Window 10 workstations to our AzureAD and users log in with their AzureAD account details.

How can I use InTune device policies to govern password complexities for AzureAD a specific group of users? I have attempted to use the password section of "Device Configuration" but that appears to only apply to local user account.

The policy we would like to create is:

- Password change frequency - 30 days
- Minimum password length - 10 characters
- Complex (Uppercase, lowercase, alpha numeric and symbols)
- Apply to a specific group of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have the intune device policy govern password requirements for azureAD. That's not how it works, intune would only govern settings for local accounts on either windows or mobiles. As AzureAD has its own password requirements that is set by Microsoft and cannot be changed. here are the Microsoft settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts

If you had azureAD DS (Domain Services) you could set a password policy on that, which would accomplish what you want, however azure AD DS would need to be set up. and machines would need to be joined to it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/password-policy